# fast parallel TcpClients with await BeginConnect new Thread Pulse

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am trying to establish a TCP connection with a number of IPs in parallel, and do that as fast as possible. I have converted some older code to use AsyncCTP for that purpose, introducing the parallelism.

### Changes to Design and Speed, and Accessing Successful Connections?

My question is three-fold:

- How bad is the following flow / what should I change?

  - i.e. the await starts a bunch of parallel TcpRequest threads,
  - but within each TcpRequest there is a tcpClient.BeginConnect
  - as well as another thread being spawn for reading (if connection is successful)
  - and the writing to the stream is done with a Wait / Pulse mechanism in a while loop.
- Secondly, how could i make the process of connecting to a number of targets faster?

  - Currently, if the ip:port targets are not actually running any servers, then i get the "All Done" printed after about 18 seconds from the start, when trying to connect to about 500 local targets (that are not listening, and thus fail, on those ports).
- How could i access the WriteToQueue method of successful connections, from the *mothership*?

### Async Mothership Trying to Connect to All Targets in Parallel

```
// First get a bunch of IPAddress:Port targets
var endpoints = EndPointer.Get(); 
// Try connect to all those targets
var tasks = from t in topList select TcpRequester.ConnectAsync(t);
await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
Debug.WriteLine("All Done");
```

### Static Accessor for Individual TcpRequest Tasks

```
    public static Task<TcpRequester> ConnectAsync(IPEndPoint endPoint)
    {
        var tcpRequester = Task<TcpRequester>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                             {
                                             var request = new TcpRequester();
                                             request.Connect(endPoint); 
                                             return request;
                                             }
                                             );
        return tcpRequester;
    }
```

### TcpRequester with BeginConnect TimeOut and new Thread for Reading

```
    public void Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint)
    {
           TcpClient tcpClient = null;
           Stream stream = null;
           using (tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
                tcpClient.SendTimeout = 1000;
                IAsyncResult ar = tcpClient.BeginConnect(endPoint.Address, endPoint.Port, null, null);
                WaitHandle wh;
                wh = ar.AsyncWaitHandle;
                try
                {
                    if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), false))
                    {
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    }

                    if (tcpClient.Client != null)
                    {
                        // Success
                        tcpClient.EndConnect(ar);
                    }

                    if (tcpClient.Connected)
                    {
                        stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    }

                    // Start to read stream until told to close or remote close
                    ThreadStart reader = () => Read(stream);
                    // Reading is done in a separate thread
                    var thread = new Thread(reader);
                    thread.Start();

                    // See Writer method below
                    Writer(stream);

                } finally
                {
                    wh.Close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (tcpClient != null)
                tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
    }
```

### Writing to Stream with Wait and Pulse

```
    readonly Object _writeLock = new Object();

    public void WriteToQueue(String message)
    {
            _bytesToBeWritten.Add(Convert(message));

            lock (_writeLock)
            {
                 Monitor.Pulse(_writeLock);
            }
    }

    void Writer(Stream stream)
    {
        while (!_halt)
        {
            while (_bytesToBeWritten.Count > 0 && !_halt)
            {
                // Write method does the actual writing to the stream:
                if (Write(stream, _bytesToBeWritten.ElementAt(0)))
                {
                    _bytesToBeWritten.RemoveAt(0);
                } else
                {
                    Discontinue();
                }
            }
            if (!(_bytesToBeWritten.Count > 0) && !_halt)
            {
                lock (_writeLock)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(_writeLock);
                }
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Discontinuing Writer and TcpRequester");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few red flags that pop out at a cursory glance.

- You have this `Stream` that is accepting reads and writes, but there is no clear indication that the operations have been synchronized appropriately. The documentation does state that a `Stream`'s instance methods are not safe for multithreaded operations.
- There does not appear to be synchronization around operations involving `_bytesToBeWritten`.
- Acquiring a `lock` solely to execute `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` is a little weird, if not downright incorrect. It is basically equivalent to using a `ManualResetEvent`.
- It is almost never correct to use `Monitor.Wait` without a `while` loop. To understand why you have to understand the purpose of pulsing and waiting on a `lock`. That is really outside the scope of this answer.
- It appears like the `Writer` and `WriteToQueue` methods are an attempt to generate a producer-consumer queue. The .NET BCL already contains the innards for this via the `BlockingCollection` class.

For what it is worth I see nothing flagrantly wrong with the general approach and usage of the `await` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I take your points! As a follow-up, do you see a wastage of threads / can you see any specific ways that might make the parallel connections execute faster? (p.s. the `Monitor.Wait` is in a `while` loop if i understand you correctly)